# Create Vue.js + Chart.js charts using datasets stored outside in a csv file

Tags: csv, vue.js, dataset, chart.js

I am using Vue.js together with Chart.js. How can I use my datasets which are in `*.csv` file, instead of hard-coding the data?

```
import BarChart from '../BaseCharts/Bar'

export default BarChart.extend({
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data One',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
        }
      ]
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webpack then you could require them using the `file-loader` and parse them with a JavaScript library like [http://papaparse.com](http://papaparse.com/) or use the `dsv-loader` and have it return a JSON object.

All that is left to do is pre-processing on the data to get it into a format Chart.js understands and you should get something close to what you are after.